# JMeter: Stepping Thread Group vs Concurrency Thread Group - why newer is better?

Tags: jmeter

I've done web search for `site:stackoverflow.com JMeter: Stepping Thread Group vs Concurrency Thread Group` and have not found much. 
On https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/:

> Stepping Thread Group This plugin is deprecated and should not be
>   used. Use Concurrency Thread Group instead.
>
> However, time goes by and probably better alternative has been
>   offered: Concurrency Thread Group

I've used `Concurrency Thread Group` and just found about `Stepping Thread Group`. As I've seen deficiency of `Concurrency Thread Group` is that is does not do (and no options for) ramp-up for steps.

[image]

But `Stepping Thread Group` (below) have it.

[image]

How then `Concurrency Thread Group` is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that [Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread/) is missing features of Stepping

> Concurrency Thread Group doesn’t provide the ability to define initial delay, step transition and ramp-down - which the Stepping Thread Group does.

I think the documentation was before [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) was introduced

Ultimate Thread Group is the replacement for all plugin's thread group,including Stepping and Concurrency:

> "Ultimate" means there will be no need in further Thread Group plugins. The features that everyone needed in JMeter and they finally available:
>
> infinite number of schedule records
> separate ramp-up time, shutdown time, flight time for each schedule record
> and, of course, trustworthy load preview graph

Comment: thank you. But looks liken Ultimate have same deficiency as HP Load Runner which I used before JMeter - for product out of the box you have to enter each step manually. Is there any easy way to add many (similar) steps at once?

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov you can click Copy Row multiple times to duplicate row ( or duplicate data when editing jmx file)

Comment: in my professional experience on performance testing "Breakpoint testing" ("capacity testing") https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing is most common type of test we do and for it `Stepping Thread Group` is most easily configured one. Is there reasons not to use it above newer ones?

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov Not always best practices suite all companies/teams, you can decide to chose whatever is suitable to you, theoretically you can even enhance Stepping thread group because it's open source

Answer (score 1):

> As I've seen deficiency of Concurrency Thread Group is that is does not do (and no options for) ramp-up for steps.

that's not true, there is `Ramp-Up Steps Count` where you can specify the number of steps so the number of users will be evenly distributed by the number of steps:

[image]

If the above functionality is not sufficient be aware that you can connect the Concurrency Thread Group to the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so Concurrency Thread Group would stick to the Throughput Shaping Timer load pattern. And the Throughput Shaping Timer provides full flexibility in terms of ramping up, ramping down, holding the load, etc.

[image]